# thread in single processor system

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

these two thread run concurrently in a shared memory (all variables are
shared between the two threads):
**Thread A**

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
  x = x + 1;
}
```

**Thread B**

```
for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
   x = x + 2;
}
```

Assume a single-processor system
a- Give a concise proof why x≤15 when both threads have completed.
b- Suppose we replace x = x+2 in Thread B with x = x-1 what will be the value of X.

I do not understand this question and I google it and I found answer but I can not get it 
I wanna some explanation for it.

Comment: Stackoverflow tends to be pretty open about helping people with homework, but please tag it as such.

Comment: @gbtimmon - Actually, the [homework] tag is now obsolete.

Comment: @gbtimmon the homework tag is deprecated and is not to be used.

Comment: @ArjunShankar gbtimmon I can read over and over again **why** they removed the homework tag, still doesn't make sense. Lots of questions loose their context without this tag and can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the threading works perfectly, the highest value 'x' can have is 15.  This all depends on the scheduler of the operating system.

Note that I am assuming the initial value of x is 0!
Lets say that Thread A and Thread B are serialized.
The value of x after Thread A is complete will be 5.

```
 i | x
-------
 0 | 1
 1 | 2
 2 | 3
 3 | 4
 4 | 5
```

The value of x going into Thread B will be 5, resulting x to be a final value of 15

```
 i | x
-------
 0 | 7
 1 | 9
 2 | 11
 3 | 13
 4 | 15
```

Now, things typically don't happen this way, and a thread will both read an initial value of x and do their addition, then write their modified value back into memory.  The following can happen.

```
Thread A reads the value 'x' as 0
Thread B reads the value 'x' as 0
Thread A adds 1 to x making its local copy of x, 1
Thread B adds 2 to x making its local copy of x, 2
Thread A writes its modified value of x as 1
Thread B writes its modified value of x as 2 (overwriting Thread A's modification)
```

Therefore, x will be no more than 15, but depending on the scheduler, will be less!

Comment: The this is typically called a `race condition` see here for more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 2):

**a)** 
Instruction `x=x+1` is not single instruction at low level and It consist of sequence of  read x, then add 1 to x and then update x's memory . Hence it may be happen two threads read same value of x.

Suppose, if two threads read same value of x variable then update x and write back to x this cause x < 15.

**b)**
For the same reason value of x may be between 0 to 5 if your instruction is `x=x-1`.

---

**Try this you will learn more!**
compile your c code with `-S option` it will create a compiled assemble code for your program. Then you can `understand x = x + 1  is not a single instruction`. And switching between threads can be possible before completion of `x = x + 1`  instruction hence its not atomic.